# Почему команда в кнопке выполняется сразу после запуска программы, и не выполняется при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-faq

Почему команда в кнопке выполняется сразу после запуска файла, а при нажатии не выполняется?
Т.е когда запускаю файл сразу печатает `1`, а при следующих нажатиях ничего не происходит.

```
import tkinter
root = Tk()
b = Button(root,text = 'кнопка',command = print(1) )
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что вы подаете сигнал на выполнении функции `print()`,
чтобы все работало корректно можете написать так:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
b = tkinter.Button(root, text='кнопка', command=lambda: print(1))
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

---

Или так:

```
import tkinter


def func_print():
    print(1)


root = tkinter.Tk()
b = tkinter.Button(root, text='кнопка', command=func_print)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

---

Более правильное объяснения от [@jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775139/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0-tkinter-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0/775146#comment1212339_775146)

> В выражении: `f(g())` сперва вызывается `g()` функция, а затем её
>   результат передаётся в f функцию. От того что аргумент по имени
>   передаётся (`command` в данном случае), его вычисление не будет
>   откладываться.

Comment: "подаете сигнал" это как-то загадочно :) В выражении: `f(g())` сперва вызывается `g()` функция, а затем её результат передаётся в `f` функцию. От того что аргумент по имени передаётся (`command` в данном случае), его вычисление не будет откладываться.¶ Я видел как в таких случаях обвиняли GIL (когда в Thread target аргумент передают) ;)

Comment: Еще вариант через partial: `from functools import partial` ... `b = tkinter.Button(root, text='кнопка', command=partial(print, 1))`

Comment: @insolor как по мне это выглядит более звращенно, но как вариант)

Comment: @Twiss, ну так да, для особых любителей функционального программирования)