# Как сделать программу с изменением label при помощи функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Мне нужно сделать программу, которая имеет в себе `label` с рандомным числом в диапазоне 1000 и кнопку `start`, при нажатии на нее на `label` менял значение(менял свое число).

Как это реализовать?

Мой код:

```
import tkinter, random 
root = tkinter.Tk() 
def change(): 
    r = random.randrange(1000) 
    lab['text'] = r 
lab = tkinter.Label(root, text="") 
lab.grid(row=1, column=1) 
btn = tkinter.Button(text='Change', command=change()) 
btn.grid(row=1, column=2) 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Первый раз слышу про число лэйбла, что это?

Comment: на каком моменте застряли? Если не знаете как начать, то отдельные Stack Overflow вопросы задайте: "как текст показать в tkinter Label", "как по нажатию на кнопку действие совершить в tkinter", "как изменить текст tkinter Label", "как сгенерировать случайное число в Питоне", "как число в строку преобразовать"

Comment: `import tkinter, random
 
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    def change():
        r = random.randrange(1000) 
        lab['text'] = r

    lab = tkinter.Label(root, text="")
    lab.grid(row=1, column=1)
    btn = tkinter.Button(text='Change', command=change())

    btn.grid(row=1, column=2)
    root.mainloop()`

Comment: Похожий вопрос [Библиотека tkinter. почему команда в кнопке выполняется сразу после запуска?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775139/%d0%91%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-tkinter-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0/775146#775146)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему команда в кнопке выполняется сразу после запуска?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775139/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ошибка здесь**

```
btn = tkinter.Button(text='Change', command=change())
```

**Лишние скобки**

**Надо так**

```
btn = tkinter.Button(text='Change', command=change)
```