# Не выводит функцию при нажатий кнопки

Tags: python, функции, tkinter

Я хотел сделать простую программу определения процедуры для расчета периметра и площади треугольника по его сторонам в python tkinter. Вот мой код:

```
from tkinter import*
from math import*
def funk(*args):
    p=a+b+c
    p1=a1+b1+c1
    po=p1+p
    s=float(math.sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c)))
    s1=float(math.sqrt(p1*(p1-a1)*(p1-b1)*(p1-c1)))
    so=s1+s
    return po,so
root = Tk()
root.title('ППИС 6 зертханалык жумыс')
zadanie = Label(root, text=" Определить процедуру для расчета периметра и площади треугольника по его сторонам ", bg="blue", fg="white")
entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_2 = Entry(root)
entry_3 = Entry(root)
entry_4 = Entry(root)
entry_5 = Entry(root)
entry_6 = Entry(root)
button_1 = Button(root,text="Вычислить", command=funk)
label_1 = Label(root, text="введите число")
label_2 = Label(root, text="введите число")
label_3 = Label(root, text="введите число")
label_4 = Label(root, text="введите число")
label_5 = Label(root, text="введите число")
label_6 = Label(root, text="введите число")
label_7 = Label(root)

zadanie.grid(row=0,column=0)
entry_1.grid(row=2,column=0)
label_1.grid(row=1,column=0)
label_2.grid(row=3,column=0)
entry_2.grid(row=4,column=0)
entry_3.grid(row=6,column=0)
entry_4.grid(row=8,column=0)
entry_5.grid(row=10,column=0)
entry_6.grid(row=12,column=0)
label_3.grid(row=5, column=0)
label_4.grid(row=7, column=0)
label_5.grid(row=9, column=0)
label_6.grid(row=11, column=0)
label_7.grid(row=13, column=0)
button_1.grid(row=5,column=1)
def command(event):
    a=int(entry_1.get())
    b=int(entry_2.get())
    c=int(entry_3.get())
    a1=int(entry_4.get())
    b1=int(entry_5.get())
    c1=int(entry_6.get())
    label_7["text"] = funk(event)
    button_1.bind("<Button-1>",  command(event))
root.mainloop()
```

пишет ошибку

> TypeError: funk() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'a'

помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: Вы не задали переменную `а` так же [посмотрите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/775146/255866)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути вам не нужна дополнительная функция для обозначения переменных(потому что в данном случае у вас  функция `command` не вызывается и не передает аргументы т.к. она содержит локальные переменные) используйте `lambda` и меняйте текст через нее .

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, Button
import math


def func():
    a = int(entry_1.get())
    b = int(entry_2.get())
    c = int(entry_3.get())
    a1 = int(entry_4.get())
    b1 = int(entry_5.get())
    c1 = int(entry_6.get())
    p = a+b+c
    p1 = a1+b1+c1
    po = p1+p
    s = float(math.sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c)))
    s1 = float(math.sqrt(p1*(p1-a1)*(p1-b1)*(p1-c1)))
    so = s1+s
    return po, so


root = Tk()
root.title('ППИС 6 зертханалык жумыс')
zadanie = Label(root, text=" Определить процедуру для расчета периметра и площади треугольника по его сторонам ", bg="blue", fg="white")
entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_2 = Entry(root)
entry_3 = Entry(root)
entry_4 = Entry(root)
entry_5 = Entry(root)
entry_6 = Entry(root)
button_1 = Button(root,text="Вычислить", command=lambda: label_7.config(text=func()))
label_1 = Label(root, text="введите число")
label_2 = Label(root, text="введите число")
label_3 = Label(root, text="введите число")
label_4 = Label(root, text="введите число")
label_5 = Label(root, text="введите число")
label_6 = Label(root, text="введите число")
label_7 = Label(root)

zadanie.grid(row=0, column=0)
entry_1.grid(row=2, column=0)
label_1.grid(row=1, column=0)
label_2.grid(row=3, column=0)
entry_2.grid(row=4, column=0)
entry_3.grid(row=6, column=0)
entry_4.grid(row=8, column=0)
entry_5.grid(row=10, column=0)
entry_6.grid(row=12, column=0)
label_3.grid(row=5, column=0)
label_4.grid(row=7, column=0)
label_5.grid(row=9, column=0)
label_6.grid(row=11, column=0)
label_7.grid(row=13, column=0)
button_1.grid(row=5, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```