# Код работает, но функция выполняется ДО нажатия на кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter import*

class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        self.load()

    def load(self):
        name = askopenfilename()

        if name:
            self.df = pd.read_excel(name)

        self.create_widgets()

    def method(self, df1):
        df1['Proverka']=0
        return df1

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.label=Label(self)
        self.label.pack()
        self.button=Button(self, text="say", command=self.method(self.df)).pack() 

        self.down()  

    def down(self):
        to_file = askdirectory()
        z= "/"+str(11)+'.xlsx'
        if to_file:
            self.df.to_excel(to_file +z)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().mainloop()
```

Comment: Смысл кода в том, что необходимо выбрать файл, выполнить какую-то операцию с ним и выбрать директорию, куда положить файл(именно директорию, это важно). К сожалению, операция над файлом выполняется раньше, чем нажатие на клавишу. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему команда в кнопке выполняется сразу после запуска?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775139/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3):

Если `f` это функция, то `f()` вызывает эту функцию в Питоне, поэтому `command=self.method(self.df)` вызывает `method` метод, а результат вызова устанавливается как `command`.

Если вы хотите задержать вызов метода пока кнопка не нажата, то можно обернуть в `lambda`:

```
command=lambda: self.method(self.df)
```

В сторону: нет нужды явно передавать `self.df`. Вы можете использовать `self.df` внутри `self.method` напрямую. В этом случае можно было бы написать просто:

```
command=self.method
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu, Text
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import pandas as pd

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Редактор")

        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Файл", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="открыть", command=self.open)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="сохранить", command=self.save)

        self.text = Text(self.parent, width=700, height=500, bg="darkgreen", fg='white', wrap=WORD)
        self.text.pack()

    def open(self):
        name = askopenfilename()
        self.document = pd.read_excel(name)
        self.text.insert(1.0, self.document)

    def save(self):
        directory = askdirectory()
        path = "/" + str(11) + '.xlsx'

        self.document.to_excel(directory + path)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("700x500+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Дальше сам.**