# Не работает кнопка (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

Пишу калькулятор. Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def add_data(self, data):
        if "0" <= data <= "9":
            self.data_.append(data)
            self.is_symbol = False
            self.is_point = False

        elif data == "=":
            if not self.is_point:
                if not self.is_symbol:
                    self.calculate()

        elif data == ".":
            if not self.is_symbol:
                if not self.is_point:
                    self.data_.append(data)
                    self.is_point = True
                    self.is_symbol = True

        else:
            if not self.is_symbol and not self.is_point:
                self.data_.append(data)
                self.is_symbol = True
                self.is_point = True
            elif self.is_symbol and not self.is_point:
                self.data_[len(self.data_) - 1] = data

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.is_point = True
        self.is_symbol = True
        self.data_ = ["0"]
        self.lbl = Label(self, text="")
        self.lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W)
        Button(self,
               text="/",
               command=self.add_data("/")
               ).grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text="*",
               command=self.add_data("*")
               ).grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text="-",
               command=self.add_data("-")
               ).grid(row=1, column=2, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text="7",
               command=self.add_data("7")
               ).grid(row=2, column=0, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text="8",
               command=self.add_data("8")
               ).grid(row=2, column=1, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text="9",
               command=self.add_data("9")
               ).grid(row=2, column=2, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text="4",
               command=self.add_data("4")
               ).grid(row=3, column=0, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text="5",
               command=self.add_data("5")
               ).grid(row=3, column=1, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text="6",
               command=self.add_data("6")
               ).grid(row=3, column=2, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text="1",
               command=self.add_data("1")
               ).grid(row=4, column=0, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text="2",
               command=self.add_data("2")
               ).grid(row=4, column=1, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text="3",
               command=self.add_data("3")
               ).grid(row=4, column=2, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text="0",
               command=self.add_data("0")
               ).grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text=".",
               command=self.add_data(".")
               ).grid(row=5, column=2, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text="+",
               command=self.add_data("+")
               ).grid(row=2, column=3, rowspan=2, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)
        Button(self,
               text="=",
               command=self.add_data("=")
               ).grid(row=4, column=3, rowspan=2, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)

    def calculate(self):
        print("WORKING")
        numbers = []
        symbols = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
        number = "0"
        for symbol in self.data_:
            if symbol not in symbols:
                number += symbol
            else:
                numbers.append(number)
                number = "0"
                numbers.append(symbol)
        for i in range(0, len(numbers) - 2, 3):
            if numbers[i + 1] == "+":
                res = int(numbers[i]) + int(numbers[i + 2])
                numbers[i + 2] = res
            elif numbers[i + 1] == "-":
                res = int(numbers[i]) - int(numbers[i + 2])
                numbers[i + 2] = res
            elif numbers[i + 1] == "/":
                res = int(numbers[i]) / int(numbers[i + 2])
                numbers[i + 2] = res
            else:
                res = int(numbers[i]) * int(numbers[i + 2])
                numbers[i + 2] = res
        self.lbl.configure(text=numbers[len(numbers) - 1])
        print(numbers[len(numbers) - 1])


root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Никаких ошибок не получаю, всё запускается. Строчка `print("WORKING")` сделана для того, чтобы понять входит ли программа в функцию `calculate`. Как оказалось, не входит, даже при соблюдении всех условий (точка не последний символ, арифметический знак не последний символ - булевые величины `is_point` и `is_symbol` отвечают за проверку этих условий).

Comment: Совет: кнопки создавайте с циклом фор.

Comment: Переоткрыл вопрос, потому что тут все-таки две проблемы - неработающие кнопки и создание кнопок по отдельности вместо цикла.

Comment: Переносите строчку print("WORKING") вверх по коду, пока не обнаружите то место, после которого код перестает работать так, как хочется. Ведь, может быть, переменные равны совсем не тому, чему вам думается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Кнопки не работают, потому что у вас при создании кнопок методы сразу вызываются, а не привязываются к кнопке. Для решения этой проблемы нужно вызов метода обернуть в lambda: `command=lambda: self.add_data("/")`
   Аналогично вот этому вопросу: [Код работает, но функция выполняется ДО нажатия на кнопку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/838169/1365)
2. Кнопки создаются вручную, хотя логично было бы это делать в цикле. Пример реализации:

   ```
   # Символы обернул в iter, чтобы можно было получать следующий символ с помощью next:
   symbols = iter("/*-789456123")

   for row in range(1, 5):  # цикл от 1 до 4
       for col in range(3):
           symbol = next(symbols)
           Button(self,
               text=symbol,
               # Тут нужно передавать символ через параметр, иначе символ будет браться из локальной переменной symbol (ее последнего значения):
               command=lambda sym=symbol: self.add_data(sym)  
           ).grid(row=row, column=col, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)

   # Дальше параметры grid меняются нерегулярно, можно их хранить как словари
   params = [
       ("0", dict(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)),
       (".", dict(row=5, column=2, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)),
       ("+", dict(row=2, column=3, rowspan=2, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10)),
       ("=", dict(row=4, column=3, rowspan=2, ipadx=10, ipady=6, padx=10, pady=10))
   ]

   for symbol, grid_params in params:
       Button(self,
           text=symbol,
           command=lambda sym=symbol: self.add_data(sym)  
       ).grid(**grid_params)  # передача словаря параметров в grid
   ```