# При нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
array=[]

def f(self):
    print(self.entry.get())

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.entry=Entry(root)
        self.button=Button(root,command=f(self))
        self.entry.pack()
        self.button.pack()

array.append(MyClass())
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Почему команда в кнопке выполняется сразу после запуска?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775139/Почему-команда-в-кнопке-выполняется-сразу-после-запуска)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если коротко, то вот здесь вы вызываете функцию `f`, а результат ее выполнения передаете как параметр `command` в `Button`:

```
self.button=Button(root,command=f(self))
```

А нужно передавать саму функцию, не вызывая ее.

В данном случае, раз уж ваша функция зависит от состояния объекта, то логично сделать ее методом этого объекта:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.entry=Entry(root)
        self.button=Button(root,command=self.f)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.button.pack()

    def f(self):
        print(self.entry.get())

array.append(MyClass())
```

Передавать параметр `self` в данном случае не нужно, он будет передан в метод автоматически.

Comment: Сделал также. Компилятор выдаёт "NameError: name 'f' is not defined". Пытался объявить функцию до инициализации - не помогло.

Comment: @ТимонЯблоков, исправил, попробуйте теперь

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё работает))) Пошёл дописывать прогу)))