# Я привязал hello1 к кнопке, но он выполняется до того как она будет нажата помогите это исправить

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
import time
Y=100
def hello1(X):
    C=15
    X=X-C
    print('Ваши деньги: %s'%(X))
def hello2(X):
    C=25
    X=X-C
    print('Ваши деньги: %s'%(X))
def hello3(X):
    C=20
    X=X-C
    print('Ваши деньги: %s'%(X))
tk1=Tk()
btn1=Button(tk1,text="Кофе-15 руб.",command=hello1(Y))
btn1.pack()
tk2=Tk()
btn2=Button(tk2,text="Капучино-25 руб.",command=hello2(Y))
btn2.pack()
tk3=Tk()
btn3=Button(tk3,text="Горячий шоколад-20 руб.",command=hello3(Y))
btn3.pack()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему команда в кнопке выполняется сразу после запуска?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775139/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Для передачи параметров в функцию вы можете воспользоваться лямбдой-функцией

```
#import time
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Y = 100

def hello1(X):
    C = 15
    X = X - C
    print('Ваши деньги: %s' % (X))

def hello2(X):
    C = 25
    X = X - C
    print('Ваши деньги: %s' % (X))

def hello3(X):
    C = 20
    X = X - C
    print('Ваши деньги: %s' % (X))

Button(root, text='Кофе-15 руб.', command=lambda: hello1(Y)).grid(row=1, pady=4)
Button(root, text='Капучино-25 руб.', command=lambda: hello2(Y)).grid(row=2,  pady=4)
Button(root, text='Горячий шоколад-20 руб.', command=lambda: hello3(Y)).grid(row=3, pady=4)
Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).grid(row=4, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я бы через partials передавал