# Как сделать так чтобы программа отнимала деньги уже от оставшихся, а не от ста

Tags: python

```
import time
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Y = 100

def hello1(X):
    C = 15
    X = X - C
    print('Ваши деньги: %s' % (X))

def hello2(X):
    C = 25
    X = X - C
    print('Ваши деньги: %s' % (X))

def hello3(X):
    C = 20
    X = X - C
    print('Ваши деньги: %s' % (X))

Button(root, text='Кофе-15 руб.', command=lambda: hello1(Y)).grid(row=1, pady=4)
Button(root, text='Капучино-25 руб.', command=lambda: hello2(Y)).grid(row=2,  pady=4)
Button(root, text='Горячий шоколад-20 руб.', command=lambda: hello3(Y)).grid(row=3, pady=4)
Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).grid(row=4, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: а зачем вы удалили предыдущий вопрос, а ответ из него используете сейчас ?

Comment: Я хочу ещё подправить эту программу

Comment: зачем вы удалили предыдущий вопрос не прокомментировав его решен он или не ?

Comment: кстати, вы помните, что вам писали в вашем предыдущем ответе по поводу использования глобальных переменных?

Comment: @S.Nick А как ТС смог удалить вопрос, если там были ответы?

Comment: @0xdb ответ был дан и не один, просто WAYTERGAY никак не отметил и никак не прокомментировал их, а просто удалил.

Comment: Во время действия этого вопроса я не был зарегистрирован

Comment: @S.Nick вопрос всё ещё [есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1077062/15479). Просто теперь его уже не отметить как принятый, т.к. другой аккаунт.

Comment: Я и не мог этого сделать т.к. не был зарегистрирован

Comment: Об этом уже было сказано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам следует использовать этот код

```
import time
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Y = 100

def hello(X):
    global Y
    Y -= X
    print('Ваши деньги: %s' % (Y))

Button(root, text='Кофе-15 руб.', command=lambda: hello(15)).grid(row=1, pady=4)
Button(root, text='Капучино-25 руб.', command=lambda: hello(25)).grid(row=2,  pady=4)
Button(root, text='Горячий шоколад-20 руб.', command=lambda: hello(20)).grid(row=3, pady=4)
Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).grid(row=4, pady=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Отметьте ответ(зелёная галочка) пжл