# Python | Не работает код который должен выводить данные в консоль

Tags: python, tkinter, requests

[image: Тут показано что я вводил]

Что делать, в консоли программа по вічислению айпи работает, а вот когда я tkinter подключил, точнее внедрил в окно оно вывело ошибку................

Код:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import *
import os
from click import style
clear = '                                                                                                                        '
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1290x720")
root['bg'] = 'black'
class gg():
    bg = 'black'
    fg = 'green'
version = Label(root, text = 'Version: 1.0.0', bg = 'black', fg = 'green').place(relx=0, rely=0.950)



def text():
    cmd = message.get()
    if cmd == 'ip':
        def info():
            import requests 
            import time 
            import json
            srip = ip.get()
            response = requests.get(f'http://ipinfo.io/{ srip }/json' )         
            print(ip)
            user_ip = response.json()[ 'ip' ] 
            user_city = response.json()[ 'city' ]  
            user_region = response.json()[ 'region' ] 
            user_country = response.json()[ 'country' ]  
            user_location = response.json()[ 'loc' ]  
            user_org = response.json()[ 'org' ]  
            user_timezone = response.json()[ 'timezone' ] 
            os.system('clear')
            all_info = f'Fore.RED + \n<Info>\nIP : { user_ip }\nСити : { user_city }\nРегион : { user_region }\nСтрана : { user_country }\nЛокация : { user_location }\nОгранизация : { user_org }\nЗона : { user_timezone }' 
        print( all_info )
        ip = ''
        iplog = Entry(textvariable=ip, width=25, bg = 'white', fg = 'red', relief='flat').place(relx=0, rely = 0.4)
        ip = StringVar()
        btnEnterip = Button(text = '[+] Ip ↵', bg = 'black', fg = 'red',command=info, relief='flat').place(relx=0.13, rely = 0.4)
        
logo = Label(root, text = 'Terminal L1meek', bg = 'black', fg = 'red').place(relx=0, rely=0.929)
telegram = Label(root, text = 'Telegram: @L1meek', bg = 'black', fg = 'red').place(relx=0.2, rely=0.929)
st1 = '1.'
str1 = Label(root, text = st1, bg = 'black', fg = 'red').place(relx=0)
st2 = '2.'
str2 = Label(root, text = st2, bg = 'black', fg = 'red').place(relx=0, rely=0.03)
st3 = '3.'
str3 = Label(root, text = st3, bg = 'black', fg = 'red').place(relx=0, rely=0.06)
st4 = '4.'
str4 = Label(root, text = st4, bg = 'black', fg = 'red').place(relx=0, rely=0.09)
st5 = '5.'
str5 = Label(root, text = st5, bg = 'black', fg = 'red').place(relx=0, rely=0.12)
st6 = '6.'
str6 = Label(root, text = st6, bg = 'black', fg = 'red').place(relx=0, rely=0.15)
st7 = '7.'
str7 = Label(root, text = st7, bg = 'black', fg = 'red').place(relx=0, rely=0.18)
st8 = '8.'
str8 = Label(root, text = st8, bg = 'black', fg = 'red').place(relx=0, rely=0.21)
st9 = '9.'
str9 = Label(root, text = st9, bg = 'black', fg = 'red').place(relx=0, rely=0.24)
st10 = '10.'
str10 = Label(root, text = st10, bg = 'black', fg = 'red').place(relx=0, rely=0.27)
st11 = '11.'
str11 = Label(root, text = st11, bg = 'black', fg = 'red').place(relx=0, rely=0.30)
st12 = '12.'
str12 = Label(root, text = st12, bg = 'black', fg = 'red').place(relx=0, rely=0.33)

btnEnter = Button(text = '↵', bg = 'black', fg = 'red',command=text, relief='flat').place(relx=0.13, rely = 0.37)
message = StringVar()
cmd = Entry(textvariable=message, width=25, bg = 'white', fg = 'red', relief='flat').place(relx=0, rely = 0.37)
root.bind('Enter', text())#Этот бинд тоже почему то не работает
root.mainloop()
```

Ошибка(чтобы её получить введите в первое поле ip, нажмите кнопку рядом с ним, появится второе вбейте туда к примеру 8.8.8.8, и нажмите кнопку рядом с ним, программа должна просто выводить данные в консоль!):

```
PY_VAR1
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "e:\VSC\pyvsc\pygame\main.py", line 27, in info
    user_ip = response.json()[ 'ip' ]
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 917, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>404: Page Not Found - IPinfo.io</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=917634022">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <link rel="manifest" href="/static/manifest.json">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="48x48" href="/static/deviceicons/android-icon-48x48.png">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="96x96" href="/static/deviceicons/android-icon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="/static/deviceicons/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/static/deviceicons/apple-icon-precomposed.png">
    <link type="image/x-icon" href="/static/favicon-96x96.png?v3" rel="shortcut icon">

    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <meta property="twitter:site" content="@ipinfoio" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://ipinfo.io//json">

    <meta property="twitter:title" content="404: Page Not Found - IPInfo.io" />
    <meta property="twitter:description" content="We're the trusted source for IP address information, handling 20 billion IP geolocation API requests per month for over 1,000 businesses and 100,000+ developers" />
    <meta property="twitter:image" content="https://ipinfo.io/static/images/social-images/generic.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://ipinfo.io/static/images/social-images/generic.jpg" />

    <script>dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];</script>

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-KT5KQLB');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<script>
    fetch('https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-KT5KQLB')
        .then((r) => {
            fetch(`/rt?r=${r.status}&u=${encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)}`)
        })
        .catch((r) => {
            fetch(`/rt?r=err&u=${encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)}`)
        });
</script>


    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://use.typekit.net" crossorigin />
    <link rel="preload" as="style" href="https://use.typekit.net/qls3unz.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/qls3unz.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'" />
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/qls3unz.css" />
    </noscript>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link rel="preload" as="style" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro&display=swap" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro&display=swap" media="print" onload="this.media='all'" />
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro&display=swap" />
    </noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.ipinfo.io/static/dist/fast.css">


</head>

<body >

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
            <div class="container position-relative">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="https://cdn.ipinfo.io/static/images/layout/logo.svg" alt="IPinfo - Comprehensive IP address data, IP geolocation API and database"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed"
type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu" aria-controls="navbarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0" id="navbarMenu">

                    <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-stretch order-1 order-lg-2 d-md-none my-4 my-sm-2  d-xl-flex ">
                        <li class="nav-item mr-0 mr-md-3">
                            <a class="btn btn-white btn-block mb-2 mb-xl-0" href="/account/login">Login</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="/signup">Sign up</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>


                    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-main order-2 order-lg-1">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownProducts" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownProducts">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                        <div class="pr-2"><a href="/products/ip-geolocation-api"><img class="p-icon" src="https://cdn.ipinfo.io/static/images/product-icons/geolocation-small.svg" alt="Geolocation" /></a></div>
                                        <div><h6><a href="/products/ip-geolocation-api">IP to Geolocation API</a></h6>
                                        <p><a href="/products/ip-geolocation-api">Customize user experiences</a></p></div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                        <div class="pr-2"><a href="/products/ranges-api"><img class="p-icon" src="https://cdn.ipinfo.io/static/images/product-icons/ranges-small.svg" alt="IP ranges" /></a></div>
                                        <div><h6><a href="/products/ranges-api">IP Ranges API</a></h6>
                                        <p><a href="/products/ranges-api">Target specific IP ranges</a></p></div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                        <div class="pr-2"><a href="/products/proxy-vpn-detection-api"><img class="p-icon" src="https://cdn.ipinfo.io/static/images/product-icons/privacy-small.svg" alt="Privacy detection" /></a></div>
                                        <div><h6><a href="/products/proxy-vpn-detection-api">Privacy Detection API</a></h6>
                                        <p><a href="/products/proxy-vpn-detection-api">Unmask users' identities</a></p></div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                        <div class="pr-2"><a href="/products/ip-company-api"><img class="p-icon" src="https://cdn.ipinfo.io/static/images/product-icons/company-small.svg" alt="Company" /></a></div>
                                        <div><h6><a href="/products/ip-company-api">IP to Company API</a></h6>
                                        <p><a href="/products/ip-company-api">Leverage anonymous leads</a></p></div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                        <div class="pr-2"><a href="/products/asn-api"><img class="p-icon" src="https://cdn.ipinfo.io/static/images/product-icons/asn-small.svg" alt="ASN" /></a></div>
                                        <div><h6><a href="/products/asn-api">ASN API</a></h6>
                                        <p><a href="/products/asn-api">Improve data enrichment</a></p></div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                        <div class="pr-2"><a href="/products/reverse-ip-api"><img class="p-icon" src="https://cdn.ipinfo.io/static/images/product-icons/domains-small.svg" alt="Domains" /></a></div>
                                        <div><h6><a href="/products/reverse-ip-api">Hosted Domains API</a></h6>
                                        <p><a href="/products/reverse-ip-api">Enhance lead generation</a></p></div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                        <div class="pr-2"><a href="/products/ip-carrier-api"><img class="p-icon" src="https://cdn.ipinfo.io/static/images/product-icons/carrier-small.svg" alt="Geolocation" /></a></div>
                                        <div><h6><a href="/products/ip-carrier-api">IP to Mobile Carrier API</a></h6>
                                        <p><a href="/products/ip-carrier-api">Identify mobile users</a></p></div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                        <div class="pr-2"><a href="/products/ip-abuse-contact-api"><img class="p-icon" src="https://cdn.ipinfo.io/static/images/product-icons/abuse-small.svg" alt="Abuse contact" /></a></div>
                                        <div><h6><a href="/products/ip-abuse-contact-api">Abuse Contact API</a></h6>
                                        <p><a href="/products/ip-abuse-contact-api">Automate abusive IP reporting</a></p></div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center mb-sm-0">
                                        <div class="pr-2"><a href="/products/whois-api"><img class="p-icon" src="https://cdn.ipinfo.io/static/images/product-icons/whois-small.svg" alt="Database download" /></a></div>
                                        <div><h6><a href="/products/whois-api">IP Whois API</a></h6>
                                        <p><a href="/products/whois-api">Get more IP insights</a></p></div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-sm-0 db-menu">
                                    <div class="pr-2"><a
href="/products/ip-database-download"><img class="p-icon" src="https://cdn.ipinfo.io/static/images/product-icons/database-download-small.svg" alt="Database download" /></a></div>
                                    <div><h6><a href="/products/ip-database-download">IP Database Download</a></h6>
                                    <p><a href="/products/ip-database-download">Access data the way you choose</a></p></div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownSolutions" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Solutions</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownSolutions">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <h5><a href="/enterprise">Enterprise</a></h5>
                                                <p><a href="/enterprise">Customized features for fast-moving organizations</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h5><a href="/integrations">Integrations</a></h5>
                                                <p><a href="/integrations">Enhance your IP address insights</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <h5 class="mb-3"><a href="/use-cases">Use cases</a></h5>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <h6><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-ecommerce">E-commerce</a></h6>

                                                <p><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-ecommerce">Personalize every customer experience</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h6><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-fintech">Financial Technology</a></h6>
                                                <p><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-fintech">Secure transactions for local and global users</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h6><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-advertising">Advertising Technology</a></h6>
                                                <p><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-advertising">Reach the right people with the right message</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h6><a href="/use-cases/cybersecurity">Cyber Security</a></h6>
                                                <p><a href="/use-cases/cybersecurity">Stay a step ahead of hidden
identities</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h6><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-telecom-companies">Telecommunication</a></h6>
                                                <p><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-telecom-companies">Provide reliable communication and connectivity</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h6><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-abm">Account Based Marketing</a></h6>
                                                <p><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-abm">Deanonymize B2B traffic at scale</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h6><a href="/use-cases/ip-based-website-customization">Web Personalization</a></h6>
                                                <p><a href="/use-cases/ip-based-website-customization">Customize experiences for each user</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h6><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-governments">Governments and Institutions</a></h6>
                                                <p><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-governments">Bolster cyber defenses and enhance citizens’ lives</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h6><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-gametech">GameTech</a></h6>
                                                <p><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-gametech">Create better gaming
experiences</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h6><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-traveltech">TravelTech</a></h6>
                                                <p><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-traveltech">Hassle free experiences for travel</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h6><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-data-enrichment">Data Enrichment</a></h6>
                                                <p><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-data-enrichment">Enrich data using anonymous web traffic</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h6><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-digital-media-entertainment">Digital Media and Entertainment</a></h6>
                                                <p><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-digital-media-entertainment">Protect and promote digital content</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h6><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-fraud-prevention">Fraud Prevention</a></h6>
                                                <p><a href="/use-cases/ip-data-for-fraud-prevention">Improve fraud risk modeling</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownWhyIPinfo" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Why IPinfo?</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownWhyIPinfo">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <h5><a href="/about">About us</a></h5>
                                                <p><a href="/about">How we became the most reliable, accurate, and in-depth source of IP address data</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <h5><a href="/customers">Customer stories</a></h5>
                                                <p><a href="/customers">How future-oriented companies use IPinfo to reach their goals</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h5><a href="/ip-data">Data</a></h5>
                                                <p><a href="/ip-data">How we deliver the most accurate IP datasets</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h5><a href="/integrations">Partners</a></h5>
                                                <p><a href="/integrations">How we collaborate with others to bring you the most accurate data on the market</a></p>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/pricing">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownResources" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Resources</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownResources">
                                <ul>
                                  <li>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <h5><a href="/developers">Documentation</a></h5>
                                                <p><a href="/developers">Explore our API documentation and libraries</a></p>
                                            </li>...
```

Я сократил ошибку, лиж бы ответ поместился, кстати я делал данную программу просто в консоли и она работала._.[[image: Код рабочей версии][2]]
[image: Вывод рабочей программы]

Comment: у вас ошибка парсинга (скорее всего пытаетесь парсить не json ответ). обратите внимание на это json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev я немного переделал код теперь ошибка в другом
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "e:\VSC\pyvsc\pygame\main.py", line 39, in text
    info()
  File "e:\VSC\pyvsc\pygame\main.py", line 29, in info
    user_ip = response.json()[ "ip" ]
KeyError: 'ip'

Comment: теперь он ругается что ключа ip в ответе нет. просмотрите дамп, что возвращает request

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev, я не совсем понял что вы имели ввиду...

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev я прописал print('response')

Comment: оно вывело <Response [404]>, я понял почему не работает, я даже ip не ввёл а он уже ищет его в коде странички которой даже пока нету

Comment: как сделать чтобы он не искал информацию раньше времени

Comment: iap = StringVar() превращает почему то любой введённый в entry в (PY_VAR1)

Comment: Исправив данную ошибку появилась таже которая выше

Comment: Потому что скобки у text нужно убрать: `root.bind('Enter', text())`, у вас сначала функция вызывается, потом ее результат биндится к Enter. А надо функцию биндить не вызывая ее. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/775139/1365

Comment: @insolor не помогает ваш способ

Comment: Мой это какой? Правильно должно быть так: `root.bind('Enter', text)` Это уже устраняет проблему, что функция text выполняется сразу при старте программы когда еще текстовые поля не заполнены. Если после этого все равно не так работает, то это нужно отдельно смотреть, что за проблема.

Comment: `iap = StringVar() превращает почему то любой введённый в entry в (PY_VAR1)` - значения из iap нужно получать через get: `iap.get()`, а не сам StringVar объект передавать куда вы его передаете.