# Как разделить переменную на переменную с таким же типом?

Tags: python, tkinter, type-error

Почему я не могу разделить переменные друг друга с одним и тем же типом? У них разные значения но один и тот же тип. Я работал с библиотекой tkinter и не нашёл подходящего для переменной другого типа. Я когда запускаю код у меня появляется ошибка "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'IntVar' and 'IntVar'" Помогите чем можете вот если что код:

```
    Label(root1, textvariable = "Вы должны переплавить" + value1 / value2 + "булыжника")


value1 = IntVar(root1)
value2 = IntVar(root1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15541719/1016033

Comment: Добавьте весь код в вопрос. Чтобы отредактировать вопрос, нажмите [edit] под ним.

Comment: Не нужно менять суть вопроса. Есть другой вопрос - задавайте его отдельно. Теперь кто зайдёт в ваш вопрос не поймёт к чему такой ответ, не относящийся к теме вопроса.

Comment: Всё я понял извините что всё так попутал

Comment: @CrazyElf я уже в дублирующем вопросе с немного другим кодом ему написал, что не нужно задавать одинаковые вопросы, нужно отредактировать изначальный вопрос, добавив весь код) Надо все-таки определиться, что нужно делать)

Comment: Так мне писать там или здесь?

Comment: Я в итоге вижу ошибку, вот тут: `command=show_day()` - нужно передавать функцию без скобок, иначе она сразу будет у вас запускаться при старте программы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему команда в кнопке выполняется сразу после запуска?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775139/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Но после того как я нажал на кнопку ничего не происходит

Comment: @il16ya, ну наверное потому что Label недостаточно просто создать, нужно еще его разместить в окне, с помощью pack, grid или place

Comment: Я добавил Label в переменную label4, разместил в окне спомощью .pack() в функции show_day() и когда я нажимаю на кнопку всё равно ничего не происходит

Answer (score 1):

`IntVar` возвращает тебе `object`, а не `int` значение.
Для получения значения нужно использовать `value1.get()`.
Также, по-моему, ты не сможешь суммировать `int` и `str`, поэтому нужно привести типы. Итоговое выражение для параметра будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
textvariable = "Вы должны переплавить" + str(value1.get() / value2.get()) + "булыжника"
```