# Превышены лимиты рекурсии

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, tkinter, рекурсия

Я ломал голову, искал ответ, но не нашёл. 
Я знаю, что `mainloop()`
превращается в цикл, который вызывает цикл и т.д. 
Но как это решить?

```
class login(Tk):
        def __init__(self):
                
                self.geometry('900x600')
                self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
                self.title('1')

#bar
                frame_photo = PhotoImage(file = 'images/menu.png')
                frame_lable = Label(self, image = frame_photo)
                frame_lable.pack()

                def started_reg():
                        self.withdraw()
                        registration()

#image list
                button_image_log = PhotoImage(file = 'images/button_log.png')
                button_image_reg = PhotoImage(file = 'images/button_reg.png')
    
#buttons
                create_button_1 = Button(self, 
                        image = button_image_log,
                        border = 0, 
                        bg = rgb((255,255,255)), 
                        #command = clicked_log,
                        activebackground = rgb((255,255,255)))
                create_button_1.place(x = 522, y = 410)

                create_button_2 = Button(self, 
                        image = button_image_reg, 
                        border = 0, 
                        bg = rgb((255,255,255)), 
                        command = started_reg(),
                        activebackground = rgb((255,255,255)))
                create_button_2.place(x = 522, y = 464)

#boxEntry
                login = Entry(self, 
                        font = ('Golos Text Regular', 15), 
                        bg = rgb((232, 232, 232)), 
                        width = 25, 
                        borderwidth=0)
                login.place(x = 529, y = 218)

                passwsord = Entry(self, 
                        font = ('Golos Text Regular', 15), 
                        bg = rgb((232, 232, 232)), 
                        width = 25, 
                        borderwidth=0)
                passwsord.place(x = 529, y = 314)


startedlogin = login()
startedlogin.mainloop()
```

Comment: Сомнения на счет `command = started_reg()`. Уверен что `()` лишние.

Comment: Это у меня в комментариях (#).

Comment: `command = started_reg()` у вас не в комментарии: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGxNB.png

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Почему команда в кнопке выполняется сразу после запуска?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/775139/1365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
from tkinter import *


class Login(Frame):                                             # +++ Login(Frame)
        def __init__(self, master):                             # +++ master
                super().__init__(master)                        # +++ master

                self.frame_photo = PhotoImage(file = 'boy33.png')
                frame_lable = Label(self, image = self.frame_photo)
                frame_lable.pack()

                def started_reg():
                        print(f'def started_reg(): ????????????') # 
# ???                   self.withdraw()
# ???                   registration()

# ------------> vvvv
                self.button_image_log = PhotoImage(file = 'Ok.png')
                self.button_image_reg = PhotoImage(file = 'Ok.png')
# ------------> ^^^^    

                create_button_1 = Button(self, 
                        image = self.button_image_log,
                        border = 0, 
                        bg = '#ccc', 
                        #command = clicked_log,
                        activebackground = '#ff0')
                create_button_1.place(x = 522, y = 410)
                create_button_1.pack()                              # +++

                create_button_2 = Button(self, 
                        image = self.button_image_reg, 
                        border = 0, 
                        bg = '#f0f', 
                        
#                        command = started_reg(),
# -----------------------------------------> v^^ <--------------------------
                        command = started_reg,
                        
                        activebackground = '#ff0')
                create_button_2.place(x = 522, y = 464)
                create_button_2.pack()                              # +++

                login = Entry(self, 
                        font = ('Golos Text Regular', 15), 
                        bg = '#fff', 
                        width = 25, 
                        borderwidth=0)
                login.place(x = 529, y = 218)
                login.pack()                                          # +++

                passwsord = Entry(self, 
                        font = ('Golos Text Regular', 15), 
                        bg = '#fff', 
                        width = 25, 
                        borderwidth=0)
                passwsord.place(x = 529, y = 314)
                passwsord.pack()                                       # +++

#vvv
root = Tk()                                                            # +++
root.geometry('900x600')                                               # +++
#root.resizable(width=False, height=False)                              # +++
root.title('title 1')                                                  # +++

# -----------> vvvvvvvvvv
startedlogin = Login(root)
startedlogin.pack()

#vvv
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: image не отображаются.

Comment: Все работает, просто VS странно работает.

Comment: @GREH установите свои изображения вместо моих.

Comment: @GREH Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour