# tkinter python параметр command

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть у многих виджетов параметр 'command=', который исполняет какую-то функцию. Я так понял в эту функцию нельзя передать параметр, например 'command=func(num)', можно это как-то обойти?

Comment: Обернуть в лямбду или использовать [partial из functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/775146/1365

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
command = lambda: func(num)
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.